# How to show bubble notification on status change (Start or stop) of windows service in windows10 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-10

I want to display bubble notification in system tray when my windows service start or stops in windows-10 , but after windows vista, there is no provision for the windows service to be interactive with the GUI or desktop, so how can I achieve this in C#??

Comment: You would have to write a separate application that runs in each users session and communicates with the service. If you're going to do that purely so that you can display notices that the user is highly likely to ignore anyway, so be it. I'd have thought time is better spent working on aspects of the system that provides *benefit* to your users.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever marketing value of service with bubble notification is many $$ higher than without :)

Comment: [ServiceTray](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceTray/) is a free app that may do what you need...

Answer (score 1):

Because a windows services cannot interact with the user-desktop, you should create a separate application (with autostart), that implements the bubble-notifications you like. I would create a simple WCF-Service in the Windows-Service so that your GUI can control the service an receive notifications.

Comment: WCF can be seen as heavyweight (cons), but can be automagically generated (pros - good for complicated protocol). In general, agree, separate application and communication